# "two children were born out of this wedlock" is the usage correct?

Tags: phrases

Stella and David married in 1995. two children were born out of this wedlock. Is the usage "out of" correct?

Comment: The phrase "born out of wedlock" refers to children whose parents were not married at the time of their birth. It would be better to say "two children were born from this union" since you are referring to the marriage in the previous sentence.

Comment: If you mean that two children were born to Stella and David whilst they were married, then the expression you have used is a confusing one. Usually the term *born out of wedlock* means that a child was born to people who were not married at the time.  It is a somewhat dated expression belonging to an era when 'illegitimate' births were stigmatised.

Comment: *born of this marriage* works, too.

Comment: Apart from the "set phrase" *born out of wedlock* (to an ***unmarried*** mother), the word [isn't used so much these days](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wedlock%2Cout+of+wedlock%2Cwedlock-(out+of+wedlock)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwedlock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20wedlock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwedlock%20-%20%28out%20of%20wedlock%29%3B%2Cc0), but OP's example (where ***out of*** means ***from, within***, so the mother *is* married) usage is perfectly "valid", and doesn't really risk ambiguity.

Comment: @StoneyB Or simply *there were two children of the marriage*.

Comment: @StoneyB: The key issue presumably being that the (perverse) alternative interpretation would be *born **outside** of this marriage* (i.e. - the ambiguity of ***out of*** can be resolved by either removing ***out*** completely or converting it to ***outside***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's technically correct, but completely unidiomatic.  I can't imagine any native speaker not hearing this as "out of wedlock."

Comment: @Chris: Not quite sure what you mean there. Personally, the fact of it being ***this*** wedlock immediately forced me to interpret ***out*** as meaning ***from*** before the (relatively far more common) collocation even occurred to me. I agree the cited usage sounds more than a trifle "dated", but "completely unidiomatic" is putting it a bit strong. And there are dozens of written instances of [*out of this/that wedlock*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22out+of+this+wedlock%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) where it invariably means ***from***, not ***outside of***, so it's not "unknown".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not that Ngrams is the final authority, but consider this: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+wedlock%2C+out+of+this+wedlock&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20wedlock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20this%20wedlock%3B%2Cc0 .  The idiom "out of wedlock" continues to gain in popularity, even today, while "out of this wedlock" doesn't even register on the graph.  Further, if you graph "wedlock" as well, you'll see that "out of wedlock" has risen to be half of all usages of the term "wedlock." The idiom dominates.

Comment: @Chris: Well, I said in the first place OP's usage is no longer common. But we're on ELU, not ELL. Are you seriously saying you think most *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts* aren't capable of (backtracking and re- ) parsing at the word ***this**?* I'd have thought most competent native speakers at large would grasp it - particularly given the ***strongly guiding context***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, I'll withdraw the suggestion that a native speaker wouldn't parse their way through this, but I think the rest of my comment is right: the statement is *technically correct* yet *unidiomatic.*  A dozen citations to the contrary aside, modern usage of "wedlock" is dominated by the idiomatic phrase "out of wedlock."  Assuming the objective is to be understood, why fight the idiom?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but "out of" has an uncomfortable echo from horse breeding:  "Stella and David mated in 1995, and there are two foals by David **out of** Stella.  Infelicitous all the way around.

Comment: @Chris: There are all sorts of reasons why one might want to use slightly unusual phrasing, up to and including archaisms (but I think it would be *way* ott to call the cited usage "archaic" - it's just dated / formal / whimsical / whatever). I assume OP (who may well be a competent native speaker, for all I know) understands the cited usage himself. And almost certainly *knows* the more common "idiomatic" set phrase. I say "idiomatic" because in practice I bet some people who understand the set phrase aren't consciously aware of what ***wedlock*** means in isolation.

Comment: @deadrat: I think it's just you. Would you still be thinking about stud farming (and ***fetlocks**?* :) if we replaced ***this wedlock*** with the syntactically-equivalent ***this match made in heaven**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It doesn't look like the OP's phrase was *ever* common usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+this+wedlock%2Cout+of+this+union%2C+out+of+this+marriage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20this%20wedlock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20this%20union%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20this%20marriage%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Chris: Perhaps I didn't make my underlying point clear. I don't think this question is about whether people with limited comprehension skills or competence in English might *misunderstand* OP's usage. I assume most people in whatever target context OP has in mind wouldn't have any difficulty understanding the intended meaning - the issue is whether it's somehow inherently *unacceptable*. And if so, ***on what grounds?*** In which context, possible ambiguity or "relative rarity" aren't necessarily significant on ELU (but they probably *are* on ELL).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I think it's just you."  Ah, if I had a nickel for every time I've heard that, I'd be a wealthy person.  But no, "wedlock" has nothing to do with it.  It's "born out of" that's the problem (for me).  And who thinks about fetlocks anyway?

Comment: I would say "... were born of this marriage."

Comment: As the song has it, "My father was the keeper of the Eddystone Light, and he married a mermaid one fine night. **Of this union there came three** -- a porpoise and a porgy and the other was me."

Answer (score 5):

**"Out of wedlock"** is an idiom and, as WS2 mentioned, it's an outdated expression but still used by some very conservative people.

- A child born **"out of wedlock"** is a child conceived and born to a woman who was not married from conception to the moment of birth, or a child conceived and born during a marriage but not the product of that marriage.  The way you phrased your question sounds like either Stella or David,  or both (you mentioned two children), had **two illegitimate children**.

> - [**"out of wedlock"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+wedlock) - Of parents not legally married to each other: born out of wedlock.

If you mean both Stella and David had those two children, better change your sentence to "Stella and David got married in 1955. Two children were the product of this union", **or simply "they had two children"**.

Comment: Can you highlight "simply, they had two children" in your answer?  (Quibble: "....simply, they have two children" is better; presumably the children are not dead.)  Or would this be (gasp!) indicating an opinion?  This site is about Usage, and it's hard to disentangle usage from opinion -- usage is the integration of many opinions over a long period.  Unless there is a legal issue, making a point of the irregularity of the children's birth is contrary to widespread current usage.   Widespread usage today would say: " Stella and David married in 1995. They have two children."

Comment: Interestingly enough, despite the musty feel of the term, Ngrams suggests that peak usage was no more than 20 years ago : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wedlock%2C+out+of+wedlock&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwedlock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20wedlock%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"Born out of wedlock" is a polite way to say "bastard".

"Born from this union" is the way you'd say the children were the legitimate offspring of both the husband and wife in the marriage.

Comment: Or less technical wording: "Stella and David married in 1995 and proceeded to have two children together"